# How to compare 2 csv files with a 2 header values and write output for status header value in a new csv file using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a software master CSV file with header values for the host den00ltm

[image: SoftwareMaster file content with header values]

After uninstalling 4 applications and installing a new application, I have Generated an installed software list from the host and stored it in a CSV file with header values

Uninstalled applications are

```
  'Application Verifier x64 External Package        10.1.17763.132'
  'C++ | Visual Fortran Compiler 17.0 for IA-32     17.0.9.279'
  'C++ | Visual Fortran Compiler 17.0 for IA-32     17.0.8.275'
  'C++ | Visual Fortran Compiler 17.0 common files  17.0.5.267'
  'Build Tools - x86                                12.0.40675'
```

Installed Application

```
  'C++ OpenMP on Intel(R) 64                        12.0.5.229'
```

[image]

Compare the newly generated CSV file from host den00ltm with a SoftwareMaster file and update the header value "Softwarestatus" with "Active" for which are the applications matching with master file, and "removed" for which ae uninstalled software and "newly added" for installed application in new CSV file along with all other header values from the master.

For example the new output CSV file should be like that

Hostname    softwarename    softwareversion    InstalledDate    softwarestatus    InstallPath Installedby
den00ltm    Tools for .Net 3.5 3.11.50727      20190829          Active
den00ltm    Build Tools - x86  12.0.40675      20210304          Removed
den00ltm    C++ OpenMP on Intel(R) 64  12.0.5.229 20120418       newly added     C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\ComposerXE-2011\

can someone Please help me on this.

Comment: You have to share your effort whatever you tried. Although this [LINK](http://www.vladsitblog.com/compare-two-csv-files-via-powershell/) would help you out.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I have formated

Comment: Please show us the code you are trying to make work.